# How to save each loop to a new file with python

Tags: python, range, output

I trying to get a json response and save it as a new file. 
To do that am I trying to loop a request through a range, then I want to save each json result as a new file

I managed to pull the request through the loop but I don't know how to save it each output in new file.

```
import requests
import json

for i in range(1, 5):
    vino = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=dk&currency_code=DKK&grape_filter=varietal&merchant_id=&min_rating=1&order_by=&order=desc&page='+str(i)+'&price_range_max=2500&price_range_min=0&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2')
    data = vino.json()
    with open('data' + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be an indentation at json.dump ?

Comment: Im new to it all. Sorry but I don't know what you mean by "indentation"

Comment: don't even start the war: spaces or tabs?

Comment: trying to use tabs

Comment: I get it, thanks and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure why Milad suggested using a `write()` — your code is basically fine, it just needs the indentation being done correctly.  you can either do:

```
import requests
import json

for i in range(1, 5):
    vino = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=dk&currency_code=DKK&grape_filter=varietal&merchant_id=&min_rating=1&order_by=&order=desc&page='+str(i)+'&price_range_max=2500&price_range_min=0&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2')
    data = vino.json()
    with open('data' + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(data, outfile)
```

note the extra spaces at the beginning of the last line, they are important and is what people are referring to with indentation.  reading some Python tutorials might help

making this code slightly nicer, you could use more of the `requests` interface by doing:

```
import requests
import json

for page in range(1, 5):
    vino = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore', params={
        'country_code': 'dk',
        'currency_code': 'DKK',
        'grape_filter': 'varietal',
        'min_rating': 1,
        'page': page,
        'wine_type_ids[]': [1, 2],
    })

    # raise an exception if this request wasn't successful
    vino.raise_for_status()

    data = vino.json()
    with open('data' + str(page) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(data, outfile)
```

if you're going to be reading the output yourself I'd "pretty print" the output with something like:

```
    with open('data' + str(page) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True,
                 indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

finally, if you're using a recent version of Python3, I'd also use the the new "format strings":

```
    with open(f'data{page}.json', 'w') as outfile:
       json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True,
                 indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

as it tends to result in easier to read code…

Comment: Thank you so much. I understod how the indentation caused the problem. I'm on my 20th hour with python and first time coding. Thanks a lot Sam!

Answer (score 0):

do it this way:

```
import requests
import json

for i in range(1, 5):
    vino = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=dk&currency_code=DKK&grape_filter=varietal&merchant_id=&min_rating=1&order_by=&order=desc&page='+str(i)+'&price_range_max=2500&price_range_min=0&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2')
    data = vino.json()
    with open('data' + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: Im getting    outfile.write(data)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Answer (score 0):

The response from the website already contains json data, but as a string. If you want to save it to the file, you can just save that string, no need to call the `json()` function on the response object. `json()` method will parse this data to python objects (dicts and lists).
You can use that after to fiddle with the data. If you just want to save it, this is not needed.

This will work:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 5):
    resp = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=dk&currency_code=DKK&grape_filter=varietal&merchant_id=&min_rating=1&order_by=&order=desc&page='+str(i)+'&price_range_max=2500&price_range_min=0&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2')
    data = resp.text

    with open("data-{}.json".format(i), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import requests
import json

for i in range(1, 5):
    vino = requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore?country_code=dk&currency_code=DKK&grape_filter=varietal&merchant_id=&min_rating=1&order_by=&order=desc&page='+str(i)+'&price_range_max=2500&price_range_min=0&wine_type_ids[]=1&wine_type_ids[]=2')
    data = vino.json()
    with open('data' + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```